# vue chartjs no strikethrough on legend click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I've recently upgraded my site from vue 2 to vue 3 and as part of that I had to upgrade the versions of vue-chartjs and chartjs too.

Now after I change the legend text of my pie chart using the `generateLabels` option (shown below), the strikethrough after clicking on a legend to hide the segment no longer works.

```js
plugins: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      generateLabels: chart => {
        const data = chart.data;

        if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
          return data.labels.map((label, i) => {
            const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            const style = meta.controller.getStyle(i);

            return {
              text: `${label}: ${this.isMoney ? StringHelper.FormatNumber(data.datasets[0].data[i], true) : data.datasets[0].data[i]}`,
              fillStyle: style.backgroundColor,
              strokeStyle: style.borderColor,
              lineWidth: style.borderWidth,
              hidden: isNaN(data.datasets[0].data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
              index: i,
            };
          });
        }

        return [];
      },
      padding: 30,
      usePointStyle: true,
    },
    position: 'left',
  },
}
```

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nm8ii?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts,src%2FApp.vue)

How do I get the strikethrough again?  I tried adding the [onclick from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633340/chartjs-legend-onclick-doesnt-strikethrough#answer-74633401) to the legend, but that just killed the pie chart completely.

By the looks of things - it's because the meta no longer has the hidden property in `meta.data[i].hidden` as it is now just `undefined`

[Click Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nm8ii-xe3xnt?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts,src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can tell if a segment is hidden now by looking at the `chart` object using the `_hiddenIndices` property:

```
hidden: chart._hiddenIndices[i] === true,
```

[Working blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nm8ii-nnhfse?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts,src%2FApp.vue)

Alternate way using `getDataVisibility` per yoduh's comment:

```
hidden: !chart.getDataVisibility(i),
```

[Working blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nm8ii-axzvfx?file=src%2FchartConfig.ts,src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: the public method for getting the same info would be `chart.getDataVisibility(i)`

Comment: Updated answer to show alternate method